# Angular @ViewChild not loading on Router Outlet load

Tags: angular, angular-decorator

I have the below screen with 4 buttons I am using to complete a tutorial on passing data between components ([Sharing Data Between Angular Components - Four Methods](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)).

I am having trouble with the @ViewChild section. There is a routerlink below the four button which populates on each button click the relevant components.
[image]

When I click the @ViewChild button, the Component shows but the message is not populated, it is empty.

[image]

When I click the @ViewChild button a second time the message is populated as expected.

[image]

I'm sure this is not the intended outcome of @ViewChild. So I need to know why it is doing this and how to correct it so the message is visible on the first click.

The tutorial says: 'we need to implement the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook to receive the data from the child' which I have done.

Below are my Parent and Child code.

**Parent**

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-view-child',
  templateUrl: './data-view-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-view-child.component.scss']
})

export class DataViewChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(ChildComponent, { static: false }) child;

  constructor() { }

  message: string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.message = this.child.message
  }

}
```

**Child**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})

export class ChildComponent {


  message = 'Hola Mundo!';
  constructor() { }
}
```

**Parent Template**

```
<div class="parent-card">
  <h1>I am the Parent component</h1>
  <h2 class="tac">Message: {{ message }}</h2>
  <app-child></app-child>
</div>
```

Please let me know why the message is not available on the first click.

Comment: what does the parent template look like

Comment: Just adding it to the question now.

Comment: are you seeing an error in your log like "expression changed after checked"?

Comment: There are no errors showing in the console.

Comment: are you running in dev mode or prod mode? the error will be suppressed in prod mode

Comment: In development mode.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzc7r6?file=src/app/app.component.ts this blitz clearly shows the error...

Comment: I don't know what to say there is no error in my console. My question is if I am following the tutorial then there should not be an error in your stackblitz either. Is that correct?

Comment: no there definitely should be an error. you're violating unidirectional data flow

Comment: OK so are you saying that the tutorial is wrong? because that would save me a lot of time and I will look for another way to send data from the child to the parent. I see @ViewChild a lot and was hoping to get it to work for myself.

Comment: the tutorial is 100% wrong. it clearly doesn't work nor should it. output events or shared services are the methods to share data from child to parent.  ViewChild has many many use cases, this is not one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue here is a violation of unidirectional data flow which is preventing change detection from triggering properly. Unidirectional data flow means that data needs to flow up or down your component tree during change detection.  Instantiating the component tree is data flowing down, but then trying to pull data out of children during instantiation means you're violating the principle by pulling it back up. Angular does not allow this as it could create an infinite change detection loop where the parent triggers child, child triggers parent, and so on.

If you're running in dev mode, you'll see an error like "expression changed after checked"... this means that something in your child has caused a change in your parent during your parents change detection cycle.

you could do a lot of hacky things like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.message = this.child.message;
  });
}
```

which will solve your issue as the timeout will trigger another round of change detection in the parent.

but the issue here is that you should not be trying to do this and shows poor architecture.  Data should come to parents in response to events, not instantiation

demo blitz: .https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzc7r6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: you can trust angularfirebase over your eyes and ears if you'd prefer. the router outlet has nothing to do with it. More likely the demo video is suppressing the error intentionally. They're selling a product at the end of the day.

Comment: Thank you for your response I will accept your answer and also for the reminder that no matter how smart you are compassion for beginner coders should always be paramount on a coding help website, a bit of 'work on the self' to remove trapped negative emotions doesn't hurt either. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `activate` event for this.

Parent component:

```
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($e)"></router-outlet>
</div>

onActivate(componentRef) {
  componentRef.myFunc();
}
```

Child component:

```
myFunc() {
  console.log("my function");
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing this in multiple places, but $e is undefined